# how to code in Mac for 8thwall web ar and test it?

Tags: 8thwall-xr, 8thwall-web

how to setup 8th wall project for web ar for Mac and use our system instead of using their web editor . I want to code in my computer and test and then upload that to their console rather then coding it in their web editor .

Answer (score 0):

> ***Steps to locally develop 8thwall webAR without using 8th wall cloud editor***

1. Create a project using 8thwall dashboard and navigate to the dashboard settings and copy the appkey.
2. copy this base [glitch get-started](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/8w-getting-started-aframe?path=index.html%3A15%3A0) project and replace the appkey with your project appkey.
3. Navigate back to the dashboard and [authorize](https://www.8thwall.com/docs/web/#device-authorization) your browser with the help of the dev-token.
4. You are ready to now use and test 8thwall development locally.
5. You can later self-host the project instead of copy pasting the code and reformatting according to the 8thwall cloud editor.

*You can also directly remix any of the [glitch projects](https://glitch.com/@8thWall) as well which is a much quicker option.*

**NOTE: The glitch projects are under-maintained hence refer docs for latest SDK version as well as syntax changes**

Answer (score 0):

You can develop locally by choosing self-hosted project option with 8thwall, then downloading [8thwall's own web repository](https://github.com/8thwall/web) to tinker with. I struggled with the 8thwall docs to figure this out but the web repository makes locally development pretty straight-forward.

Follow the steps on the [getting started guide](https://github.com/8thwall/web/tree/master/gettingstarted) ,

- firstly you'll need to create an 8thwall account and self-hosted project.
- Copy your unique App Key from the project settings page.
- Clone the source code from the repo, replacing the app key in index.html file with your own app key (this lives in the header of the html file) :

```html
    <script async src="//apps.8thwall.com/xrweb?appKey=insert-your-key-here"></script>
```

- 8thwall included a serve script, which serves your source code on local network over https. This means you can add your local URL as a trusted domain in your self-hosted project settings for testing.
- you'll need to ensure Node.js and npm are installed to run the script
- [Using the serve script](https://github.com/8thwall/web/tree/master/serve) depends on your computer, (there's instructions here for Windows also) but for the case of Mac, open a terminal in your project directory :

  ## cd <to_this_serve_directory>

  ## npm install

  ## cd ..

  ## ./serve/bin/serve -d <sample_project_location>

I use Node version 16.16.0 as I had issues with my current node version 18.12.1. You can get Node version manager npm package to help manage your Node versions.

- What's great about this is when you run the serve script from your terminal, this generates a QR code so you can test your app on a mobile device over local network. Make sure you copy the entire Listening URL into your browser, including the port number. e.g. https://245.678.0.11:8080
- Final thing to mention, don't include the port number in your trusted domains URL. e.g. https://245.678.0.11